# Magento 2 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler\Native::write()

Tags: magento2, session, fatal-error

I've been getting this error when I tried to access my project:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler\Native::write() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\magento\framework\Session\SaveHandler.php:92
>   Stack trace: #0 [internal function]:
>   Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler->write('ov6f1tnc2jcmrrv...',
>   '_session_valida...') #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\magento\module-page-cache\Model\Layout\DepersonalizePlugin.php(56):
>   session_write_close() #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(146):
>   Magento\PageCache\Model\Layout\DepersonalizePlugin->afterGenerateXml(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor)) #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(153):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}()
>    #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(78):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('ge in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\magento\framework\Session\SaveHandler.php
>   on line 92

This happened after I refreshed the browser

Comment: Did you config save the session to file ??

Comment: Yes, but i don't know where the file is saved.

Comment: Ok!. change your the folder *var/* permission to 775